# how to stop the execution of code in node js other than return

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, return

so i want to stop the code when a certain event happens but dont want to use return since the function is supposed  to return a value and if  i use it to stop the code it would reutnr an undefined value
for example  this what i need

```
  foo =() =>{
     if(event){
        //stop code 
    }else {
    return "Value"
    
    }

}
```

what i dont want to do

```
    bar =() =>{
    if(event){
    // dont want to use it since it would return an undefined value 
     return ;
    }else{
    
    return "Value" ; 
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't describe what you think you need as a solution. Describe the problem you are trying to solve (*"I somehow want a function to return but not really"* is not the problem you're trying to solve)

Comment: Also, please take the time to at least format and indent your sample code properly.

Comment: You can label the function and break it [labeled statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label)

Comment: Okay, so you have formatted your code a little. Could you also indent it properly and answer the question from my comment above - what are you *actually* trying to do?

Comment: Hi , so as i said i just want to stop the code without the usage to return  , i can handle doing it with return but just was wondering if there is another way without having to write little bit more code , mostly because the returned value would be used in another function .

Comment: You're still explaining how you think you problem should be solved and not, what your problem is. You're saying "I want to do X" and you're thinking "so I can do Y". You need to explain what Y is. Leave X to the people who answer the question.

Comment: yeah you're right , i just suck at explaining

Comment: Hard to tell. I've asked you three times now and you so far show you haven't even *tried*. I have no idea why that is, but by all means, continue to shrug it off, that's a good strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But why would you not want `undefined` to be returned? I mean... even if you have a function that returns no value at all it would still return `undefined`.

```
const a = (function(){})();
console.log(a); // undefined
```

This is just default behaviour of javascript. However, if you wish to stop execution due to a certain condition my best suggestion to you is to throw an exception and handle it.

```js
const MyFunction = (b) => {
  if (b) throw 'You shall not pass!';

  return 'I shall pass! This time...';
};

try {
  console.log(MyFunction(false));
 console.log(MyFunction(true));
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: loved how u used you shall  not pass quote , thank you btw